# Destroy an object in C#

Tags: c#, object

How to destroy an object in finally block.

For example

```
 Public void fnName()
 {
    ClassName obj = new ClassName();
    try {

    }
    catch() {

    }
    finally {
        // destroy obj here
    }
 }
```

Comment: obj = null; should be enough.......

Comment: If the Class of the object implements IDisposable, you can call obj.Dispose().

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev 
obj = null is pretty useless if the variable obj is defined within a function scope (since the reference exists on the stack). Are you trying to clean up resources?

Comment: well, since it's a local variable, you don't really have to do `obj=null;`. If it's not referenced anywhere else, the garbage collector will take care of it.

Comment: As vesan says, let the garbage collector take of it. Unless your class implements `IDisposable` don't worry about it

Comment: In order for anyone to answer your question well, you need to explain why you feel that it is important that some form of finalization occurs at a programmer specified point in time.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Do nothing. Your reference (obj) will go out of scope. Then the Garbage Collector will come along and destroy your object.

If there are (unmanaged) resources that need to be destroyed immediately, then implement the IDisposable interface and call Dispose in the finalize block. Or better, use the using statement.

**EDIT**

As suggested in the comments, when your ClassName implements IDisposable, you could either do:

```
ClassName obj = null;
try{
   obj = new ClassName();
   //do stuff
}
finally{
   if (obj != null) { obj.Dispose(); }
}
```

Or, with a using statement:

```
using (var obj = new ClassName())
{
     // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Showing his code, but rewritten to use `using` might be helpful.

Answer (score 8):

First of all, there is nothing called `Destroy` in C# language. Instead, we call `Dispose`.

The [Garbage Collector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088(v=vs.110).aspx)  automatically executes cleanup procedures when an object goes out of scope but for the unmanaged resources like sockets, db calls etc and you need to `Dispose` the object as shown below:

```
Public void fnName()
{
    ClassName obj=new ClassName();
    try
    {

    }
    catch()
    {

    }
    finally
    {
       obj.Dispose();
    }
}
```

...and implement `Dispose` functionality in your class as shown below:

```
      /// <summary>
      /// Dispose all used resources.
      /// </summary>
      public void Dispose()
      {
          this.Dispose(true);
          GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
      }

        /// <summary>
        /// Dispose all used resources.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">Indicates the source call to dispose.</param>
        private void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (this.disposed)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (disposing)
            {
                ////Number of instance you want to dispose
            }
        }
```

Another way to hinder the lifespan of an object is to write your code inside a `using` block as shown below:

```
using(var obj = new ClassName())
{
}
```

For more details for using check it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/yh598w02.aspx)

Comment: I'm not the one who downvoted but I have to ask this......can you justify why you need to call GC.SuppressFinalize(this);?

Comment: "C#" cannot do any cleanup; the .NET Framework and the Garbage Collector does. "C#" is just a programming language.